# Spring boot application is starting normally on tomcat 8 locally but i am getting 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

My spring boot application is starting normally without a single error or warning, i see all URL mappings in my console like that :

> 2019-01-25 13:26:56.157  INFO 1020 --- [ost-startStop-2]
>   s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped
>   "{[/auth/userAccessToken],methods=[POST]}" onto public
>   java.lang.String
>   com.test.garmin.controller.OAuthController.generateToken(java.lang.Long,java.lang.String,org.springframework.ui.Model)

and i see the initialization is completed :

> 2019-01-25 14:25:57.714  INFO 21244 --- [ost-startStop-1]
>   o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet
>   'measurementrest': initialization completed in 4175 ms

When i try to use my webservices all i get is 404 not found.

Packages look like that [project packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LI6Ay.jpg)
, packages containing controllers have a red line.

my application class :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages ={"com.test.garmin.controller","com.test.measurement.ws"})
@EntityScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(applicationClass, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }

    private static Class<Application> applicationClass = Application.class;
}
```

controllers are annotated like that :

```
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RequestMapping(value = "/example")
```

servlet.xml file :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.garmin.controller , com.test.measurement.ws" />
</beans>
```

I can't find where i am wrong. Most of the threads i have found insist that this is a packages problem, but i have declared my packages in application class. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the port is correct?

Comment: the port is the default 8080 i have checked it from tomcat configuration in intellij

Comment: what URL are you targetting?

Comment: Not sure if it is your problem but i would put application class at root level, to avoid scanning issues atleast if you are new to spring EDIT: i mean, like, one folder up

Comment: @Juan i have tried many urls from all the controllers none is working

Comment: Your package in screenshot looks something like "com.g...." where as your component scan package and logs says "com.test.garmin.." .Is your package consistent?

Comment: @Clomez the application class is already on the root level, the photo is just badly edited with paint cause i cannot show classes and packages names.

Comment: @Ram i did  that just for example i cannot show the packages names. I know my component scan contains the real package name and not test.

Comment: boot does not read .xml files if I am not wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was not obvious at least not for me. The artifact name was wrong, so it was deployed in tomcat webapps with name MeasurementService_war.war while my context.xml was like that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/MeasurementService"/>
```

Thats why i was getting a 404 error not found

Answer (score 0):

404 maps to not found. Please provide the URL that your client is using and also a complete code of controller. At least all the method signatures.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like api `/auth/userAccessToken` is mapped properly but you are trying to access wrong url. Please try the url like below in postman or any rest client tool with `POST` method with required parameters-

```
http://localhost:8080/your_project_context/example/auth/userAccessToken
```

Comment: the urls was correct i posted the answer to my problem thanks for the suggestion